# Spiritual invocation

Tags: adjective-phrases

> The priest read spiritual invocation and blow over him to cure his disease.

Does the Adj 'spiritual' go with the noun 'invocation' as far as sense is concerned? Here spiritual invocation means 'holy words'...

Comment: This sentence is not grammatical. Please edit your question to fix the errors in your quote: if possible, also provide a link to the text that it comes from.

Comment: Yes, the adjective "spiritual" modifies the noun "invocation".  But as JavaLatte mentions, there are at least two basic grammar mistakes in this sentence, and you should concentrate on fixing these first

Comment: Also, can you please explain what in particular concerns you? An adjective normally modifies the noun that follows it: what makes you think that something might be different in this case?

Comment: Yes... 'blew over' ... I'd really be thankful if you mentioned the other grammatical mistake in my post.

Comment: The phrase "spiritual invocation" requires an article.  It could be "the" if you're talking about one standard invocation that's always used in this situation, or "a" if not.